# __setattr__ function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, setattribute, setattr

I am trying to understand the concept of delegation in Python by using the getattr and setattr function . By basic idea is to first set the value of the attribute 'lang' in the Person class through the class Professional and then retrieve the same. The problem is that the result is an infinite loop.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name='Subhayan',job='Engineer',unique='Unique'):
        print ("Inside init function of Person")
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.salary = 50000
        self.lang = "Perl"

    def __setattr__(self,att,value):
        self.__dict__[att] = value


class Professional:
    job = 'Engineer'
    salary = 75000
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Inside Professional init function")
        self.person = Person()

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        print ("Calling the getattr function")
        return getattr(self.person, attr)

    def __setattr__(self,att,value):
        # print ("calling the setattr function setting the value of %s to %s" %(attr,value))
        self.person.__setattr__(self,att,value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Calling the script as main")
    Prof = Professional()
    print ("Salary is",Prof.salary)
    print ("name is",Prof.__class__)
    print ("Setting the value of lang")
    Prof.lang = 'Python'
    value = Prof.lang
    print ("The value of lang is ;",value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__setattr__` is called for **all** attribute setting. This includes the `self.person = Person()` call in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    print ("Inside Professional init function")
    self.person = Person()
```

This'll call `self.__setattr__('person', Person())`, which in turn tries to access `self.person`, which then calls `self.__getattr__('person')` because there is no such attribute yet. And in `__getattr__` you then end up in an infinite loop as you try to continually access `self.person`.

You could test for the specific `person` attribute in `__setattr__` (and delegate that to the base implementation):

```
def __setattr__(self, att, value):
    # print ("calling the setattr function setting the value of %s to %s" %(attr,value))
    if att == 'person':
        return super().__setattr__(att, value)
    return self.person.__setattr__(self,att,value)
```

You probably also want to add a test in `__getattr__`; if it is called with `person`, then that attribute hasn't been set yet and an `AttributeError` should be raised:

```
def __getattr__(self,attr):
    print ("Calling the getattr function")
    if attr == 'person':
        raise AttributeError('person')
    return getattr(self.person, attr)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` also apply before your instance is fully initialized.  In this case, your line `self.person = Person()`, calls `__setattr__`.  This then calls `__getattr__` (because `self.person` is not yet defined), which then recursively calls `__getattr__` again (for the same reason).

There are a few ways around this.  Perhaps the simplest is to circumvent the `__setattr__` call on the initial `self.person` assignment by doing, for instance `super().__setattr__('person', Person())`.

In general, you need to be careful when using these methods, since they may be called more often than you realize.  If your special handling applies to only a few certain attributes, you may want to use a `property` instead.

Comment: Ok so in that case i cannot initialize an object of Person from inside the __init__ method of Professional

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya: Sure you can.  Why do you think you can't?

Comment: I was thinking of replacing the call : self.person = Person() with something like : self.__dict__['person'] = Person(). This should not route calls to __setattr__. Am i correct ?

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya: Yes, you could do that as well.